# How to remove a row when getNodeChildDetails(tree legacy) is used in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid with getNodeChildDetails. I am not able to remove any row. On further debug i found that it always return null in result as isTreeLegacy is true.

Is it not possible to remove a node in this case?
Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

**To get the current node using id**

*let parentNode = this.gridApi.getRowNode(id);*

**To get the data of the parent node.**

*let objects = [parentNode.data];*

parentNode.childrenAfterGroup.map(item => {

```
 objects.push(item.data)
```

})

this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: objects });